# Is there a way to generate a report in SharePoint showing number of items added to a list/library per day?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reports

I currently have a view setup to filter by created items greater than or equal to [today]-1.  Is there another way to get this information without using a view?  I looked at Site Collection audit settings, Audit log reports, Popularity and Search Reports but they don't meet my needs.  Ideally I would like a list or count of items added to a list/library every night and I would like to filter by items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Designer Workflow or Power Automate (Used to be called as Flow) are options to do so.

In workflow you may need to turn to Rest Api to get the item count and more information.
Here is an example for you to follow:https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220502/how-to-get-a-list-of-items-created-within-a-certain-time-frame

Example for Flow:https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/FLOW-Get-Items-Filter-SharePoint-list-on-Date/td-p/85238

Answer (score 0):

If a code based solution is fine then, I would recommend a simple windows task which executes a powershell script exe which would run every morning and calculate the no. of items added to that particular list from "startdate" to "EndDate". The start date and end date can be calculated based on the current time.

Then it can send out an email or generate an excel or anything that you want to do.

If you have access to the server. Consider a timer job .